# Why the value of IF of AM is 455 kHz?

Tags: am

Why the value of intermediate frequency (IF) of amplitude modulation (AM) is 455 kHz? Why not another value?

Comment: What makes you think it is?

Comment: Related: http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-is-the-if-for-a-superhet-selected

Comment: It was developed over time for the "Broadcast Band" as a compromise between "Image Rejection" and "Selected Bandwidth". A low "IF" would have narrow bandwidth but poor Image rejection and visa versa. Some receivers designed to work well above the "Broadcast Band" use a "Higher IF" for image rejection, and a "Lower IF" to control the bandwidth skirts. I once had a very old BCB receiver that used 265kc for its IF.

Comment: @Optionparty You should post that as an answer.

Comment: I think a good answer is the referenced question posted by @VU2NHW.  Actually, the IF for AM has been various frequencies in the 4xx kHz range.

Comment: voting to close because 1) the question is based on a false premise with no source cited, and 2) [How is the IF for a superhet selected?](http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/850/how-is-the-if-for-a-superhet-selected) is the answer to this question without the false premise.